# jQuery selector: element + starts with + variable

Tags: jquery, html

Hoping for a little help with a (hopefully) syntax issue.

I need to set a selector with the following requirements:

I need the element + attribute that starts with + variable value.

I've tried something like this:

```
$("tr[id^='setA_'" + value + "]")
```

In this case i need a `<tr>` with an id beginning with setA_ and ending with a variable.

```
<tr id="setA_1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single quote is making the mess. use closing single quote after appending value from variable:

```
$("tr[id^='setA_" + value + "']")
          //----^------------^
```

Comment: Was sure i'd tried that :P thanks! Will accept in couple mins

Answer (score 0):

Your single quote is misplaced and correct it.

Use

```
$("tr[id^='setA_" + value + "']")
                            ^^^^ put here
```

Instead Of

```
$("tr[id^='setA_'" + value + "]")
               ^^^^ remove from here
```